# setBackground statement not working?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, setbackground

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Snowman extends JApplet {
//---------------------------------------------
// Draws a snowman.
//---------------------------------------------
public void paint (Graphics page)
{
    final int MID = 150;
    final int TOP = 50;

    setBackground (Color.cyan);

    page.setColor(Color.blue);
    page.fillRect(0, 175, 300, 50); // ground

    page.setColor (Color.yellow);
    page.fillOval (-40, -40, 80, 80); // sun

    page.setColor (Color.white);
    page.fillOval (MID-20, TOP, 40, 40); // head
    page.fillOval (MID-35, TOP+35, 70, 50); // upper torso
    page.fillOval (MID-50, TOP+80, 100, 60); // lower torso

    page.setColor (Color.black);
    page.fillOval(MID-10, TOP+10, 5, 5);
    page.fillOval(MID+5, TOP+10, 5, 5);

    page.drawArc(MID-10, TOP+20, 20, 10, 190, 160); // smile

    page.drawLine (MID-25, TOP+60, MID-50, TOP+40); // left arm
    page.drawLine (MID+25, TOP+60, MID+55, TOP+60); // right arm

    page.drawLine (MID-20, TOP+5, MID+20, TOP+5); // brim of hat
    page.fillRect(MID-15, TOP-20, 30, 25); // top of hat
}
}
```

This is all the code. The setBackground is stated after I declare the two final variables, thanks in advance, I got this code from a book, "Java Software Solutions", I looked over it over and over, and no luck :/ thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Snowman image]

```
//<applet code='Snowman' width=300 height=200></applet>
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Snowman extends JApplet {
//---------------------------------------------
// Draws a snowman.
//---------------------------------------------
    public void init() {
        add(new SnowmanPanel());
        validate();
    }
}

class SnowmanPanel extends JPanel {

    final int MID = 150;
    final int TOP = 50;

    SnowmanPanel() {
        setBackground (Color.cyan);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fillRect(0, 175, 300, 50); // ground

        page.setColor (Color.yellow);
        page.fillOval (-40, -40, 80, 80); // sun

        page.setColor (Color.white);
        page.fillOval (MID-20, TOP, 40, 40); // head
        page.fillOval (MID-35, TOP+35, 70, 50); // upper torso
        page.fillOval (MID-50, TOP+80, 100, 60); // lower torso

        page.setColor (Color.black);
        page.fillOval(MID-10, TOP+10, 5, 5);
        page.fillOval(MID+5, TOP+10, 5, 5);

        page.drawArc(MID-10, TOP+20, 20, 10, 190, 160); // smile

        page.drawLine (MID-25, TOP+60, MID-50, TOP+40); // left arm
        page.drawLine (MID+25, TOP+60, MID+55, TOP+60); // right arm

        page.drawLine (MID-20, TOP+5, MID+20, TOP+5); // brim of hat
        page.fillRect(MID-15, TOP-20, 30, 25); // top of hat
    }
}
```

#### General advice.

- Don't paint in a top-level Swing component.  Instead move the custom painting into a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and paint there.  For custom painting in the latter, override `paintComponent(Graphics)`
- When doing custom painting, remember to call `super.paintComponent(Graphics)`
- Set the color in the constructor (or `init()`) rather than in the paint method.

#### Other advice

- For a static image, you can also draw it to a `BufferedImage` and put the image in an `ImageIcon` in a `JLabel`.  Which is simpler.
- If this book has rushed into creating applets, toss it away.  applets are much more difficult than standard apps., and should not be attempted by newbies.

Comment: @V1rtualCurry: Note that the `applet` tag in the source make it easy to test from the command line, e.g. `/usr/bin/appletviewer SnowmanPanel.java`. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class SnowMan extends JApplet
{

    public SnowMan()
    {
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }
//---------------------------------------------
// Draws a snowman.
//---------------------------------------------


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        final int MID = 150;
        final int TOP = 50;



        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fillRect(0, 175, 300, 50); // ground

        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
        page.fillOval(-40, -40, 80, 80); // sun

        page.setColor(Color.white);
        page.fillOval(MID - 20, TOP, 40, 40); // head
        page.fillOval(MID - 35, TOP + 35, 70, 50); // upper torso
        page.fillOval(MID - 50, TOP + 80, 100, 60); // lower torso

        page.setColor(Color.black);
        page.fillOval(MID - 10, TOP + 10, 5, 5);
        page.fillOval(MID + 5, TOP + 10, 5, 5);

        page.drawArc(MID - 10, TOP + 20, 20, 10, 190, 160); // smile

        page.drawLine(MID - 25, TOP + 60, MID - 50, TOP + 40); // left arm
        page.drawLine(MID + 25, TOP + 60, MID + 55, TOP + 60); // right arm

        page.drawLine(MID - 20, TOP + 5, MID + 20, TOP + 5); // brim of hat
        page.fillRect(MID - 15, TOP - 20, 30, 25); // top of hat
    }
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: @trashgod  Generally good advice, though `JApplet` does not have a `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  (Which is why the first part of my advice re. Swing custom painting is "Don't do it in a top-level container" immediately followed by "override `paintComponent(Graphics)`".) ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
setBackground (Color.cyan);
```

It is working properly in my IDE. I also changed the color of background.It works nice and properly. No need to change the code.Make sure when you are creating the class.

Answer (score 1):

The `paint(Graphics)` method is used only to paint the parameter (in your case `page`).
The application applet background color has already been processed by this stage.

That is why you can fix the problem by setting it in the constructor:

```
public Snowman()
{
    this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use, getContentPane().setBackground()